# Can I return the $\frac{1}{4-x}$ to a geometric series?

Tags: calculus

Sometime I need to return some fraction equation to a geometric series and the above equation is one of them.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** write
$$
\frac1{4-x} = \frac 14\frac 1{1-\frac x4}
$$

Comment: ok thank you very much, the idea reached to me

Comment: do not forget to accpet the answer if it helped!

Comment: it is correct ,when |x|<4

Comment: @daryakhosrotash this is always correct, as long as you don't write the series expansion!

Comment: if |x|>4, you factorize by x and develop anyway (the reason will be $\frac{4}{x}$)  :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can.
**But** with some restrictions$$\text{for}\quad |x|\lt4 $$

$$\frac1{4-x} =\left(\frac {\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac x4}\right)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{4^2}+\frac{x^2}{4^3}+\cdots+\frac{x^r}{4^{r+1}}+\cdots$$

Comment: Is there a problem ??

Comment: I am a new user, so I don't know the law of this site.